# How to keep broadcasting from non-parallel source when one of the downstreams hangs?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

The following program prints "1" for a few seconds, and then hangs. `s1` and `s2` have parallelism of 4. Ultimately, my question is how to make the following code keep printing "1" indefinitely without changing the code in the operators and the source?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment();
    DataStreamSource<Integer> numbers = env.addSource(new SourceFunction<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public synchronized void run(SourceContext<Integer> sourceContext) {
            while (true) sourceContext.collect(0);
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel() { }

    });
    DataStream<Integer> s1 = numbers.map(d -> d + 1);
    DataStream<Integer> s2 = numbers.map(d -> {
        while (true) Thread.yield();
    });
    s1.print();
    s2.print();
    env.execute();
}
```

Maybe I got the whole Flink story wrong, but I can't see an orthodox way to multiplex from an inherently nonparallel source to multiple independent parallel pipelines without blocking on the slowest one. As per the source code, there's a broadcast in plain for-loop (`org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain:630`, v 1.5.0), which, in a case of too high backpressure, hangs the thread executing `SourceContext.collect` in monitor wait, apparently due to the full buffer of the downstream operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two downstream operators are truly independent, then I would suggest to instantiate for both operators their own source.

The problem with your application is that the two downstream operators are implicitly coupled through Flink's processing guarantees. With the exactly-once and at-least once processing guarantee, the source cannot simply continue pushing records downstream if one of the operators hangs. It has to make sure that all consumers see all elements at least once and therefore, it needs to be back-pressured as well if one of the consumers hangs.